# Pandas: How do I repeat dataframe for each value in a series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe (df) as such:

```
A B
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

And a series: `S = pd.Series(['x','y','z'])` I want to repeat the dataframe df for each value in the series. The expected result is to be like this:
result:

```
S A B
x 1 a
y 1 a
z 1 a
x 2 b
y 2 b
z 2 b
x 3 c
y 3 c
z 3 c
```

How do I achieve this kind of output? I'm thinking of merge or join but mergeing is giving me a memory error. I am dealing with a rather large dataframe and series. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Using numpy, lets say you have series and df of diffenent lengths

```
s= pd.Series(['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A']) #added a character to s to make it length 4
s_n = len(s)
df_n = len(df)
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,s_n, axis = 0), columns = df.columns, index = np.tile(s,df_n)).rename_axis('S').reset_index()

    S   A   B
0   X   1   a
1   Y   1   a
2   Z   1   a
3   A   1   a
4   X   2   b
5   Y   2   b
6   Z   2   b
7   A   2   b
8   X   3   c
9   Y   3   c
10  Z   3   c
11  A   3   c
```

Comment: yeah, i also was working on solution based on `pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(...))`, but you were faster ;)

Comment: Will you feel better if I say that that happens with me all the time? :)

Comment: what if the lengths of the series and dataframes are not identical and are unknown?

Comment: @Praneetha, you can say n = len(s) and then use n in place of 3 in my answer

Comment: I just tested this but ran into a memory error. Is there a way to do it in chunks? Thanks!

Comment: @A-Za-z yes, the issue is with the memory overload. Breaking into chunks would be a better idea. But im not sure how to do it

Comment: @Praneetha, How many repeats are you going for? You can create two or more dataframes with fewer repeats and then something like pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])

Comment: @A-Za-z yeah this wouldnt work for me then. My dataframe's length is close to 90K and the series has a length on 80

Comment: I keep running into type error: 'str' object is not callable. Line 3998, in transform index, items = [func(x) for x in index]. Could some please explain this?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

here is a bit changed [@A-Za-z's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43899888/5741205) which might be bit more memory saving, but it's slower:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(df) * len(S)))

for col in df.columns:
    x[col] = np.repeat(df[col], len(s))

x['S'] = np.tile(S, len(df))
```

---

**Old incorrect answer:**

```
In [94]: pd.concat([df.assign(S=S)] * len(s))
Out[94]:
   A  B  S
0  1  a  x
1  2  b  y
2  3  c  z
0  1  a  x
1  2  b  y
2  3  c  z
0  1  a  x
1  2  b  y
2  3  c  z
```

Comment: My desired output is not this. I want the output to repeat the initial dataframe for each value in the series

Comment: I know the examples are both of length 3, but if I understand OP correctly, it may be len(df) instead

Comment: the lengths may or maynot be identical.. i should have mentioned that

Comment: @Praneetha, can you post a reproducible data sets and a desired one?

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'B': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}})
S = pd.Series(['x','y','z'], name='S')
```

**Solution**

```
#Convert the Series to a Dataframe with desired shape of the output filled with S values.

#Join df_S to df to get As and Bs
df_S = pd.DataFrame(index=np.repeat(S.index,3), columns=['S'], data= np.tile(S.values,3))

df_S.join(df)

Out[54]: 
   S  A  B
0  x  1  a
0  y  1  a
0  z  1  a
1  x  2  b
1  y  2  b
1  z  2  b
2  x  3  c
2  y  3  c
2  z  3  c
```